# How did IGListKit update sectionHeader?

Tags: ios, iglistkit

When I use `ListBindingSectionController<ListDiffable>` for sections, I can not find out any way to update header.I have try  Calendar Demo without any clues.Or  ListBindingSectionController is just Not Support Updating Header or Footer?.
Cells in IGListKit is `ListBindable`, cells update in `func bindViewModel`.
Headers or footers is just a `view`,there is no way to update.

Comment: `ListAdapter.reloadObjects` or `ListAdapter.reloadData()` updates header and footer.I do not think it's a good solution.